# How to check with Ant if files contain a string a OR a string b

Tags: ant

I'm looking for a way to make this code snippet work but with one of the three contains being true. So OR instead of AND.

```
<condition property="warningFilesFound">
  <resourcecount when="greater" count="0">
    <fileset id="warnings-fileset-id" dir="${target.dir}/xref" includes="**/*.warnings">
      <contains text="requires &#34;CHARACTER&#34;,&#34;RAW&#34; or &#34;COLUMN&#34; for double-byte or multi-byte(UTF8) languages. (3619)"/>
      <contains text="requires &#34;CHARACTER&#34; or &#34;RAW&#34; for double-byte languages. (2363)"/>
      <contains text="requires &#34;CHARACTER&#34;, &#34;RAW&#34;, &#34;COLUMN&#34; or &#34;FIXED&#34; for double-byte or multi-byte(UTF8) languages. (3623)"/>
    </fileset>
  </resourcecount>
</condition>
```

Only one of the three contains should be true. In this code snippet all three contains must be true. Regular expression?

Comment: OR implies at least one true, rather than exactly one - presume OR is ok? (Rather than a three-way XOR?)

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to wrap an [`<or>` selector](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/selectors.html#orselect) round the contain elements, something like this:

```
<fileset id="warnings-fileset-id" dir="${target.dir}/xref" includes="**/*.warnings">
  <or>
    <contains text="requires &#34;CHARACTER&#34;,&#34;RAW&#34; or &#34;COLUMN&#34; for double-byte or multi-byte(UTF8) languages. (3619)"/>
    <contains text="requires &#34;CHARACTER&#34; or &#34;RAW&#34; for double-byte languages. (2363)"/>
    <contains text="requires &#34;CHARACTER&#34;, &#34;RAW&#34;, &#34;COLUMN&#34; or &#34;FIXED&#34; for double-byte or multi-byte(UTF8) languages. (3623)"/>
  </or>
</fileset>
```